# Unresolved reference at compile but available by Intellisense

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter

I'm working on an audio processing library for Flutter, and I'm running into an issue with one of my native Kotlin classes. In the code sample below, the compiler is complaining that the call to `copyInto` on the `samples` array is an unresolved reference. As far as I can tell, I've made sure that it is an `IntArray`, and Intellisense in Android Studio even brings up `copyInto` as an option when I type "samples.".

Here is my class code:

```
package com.----.audio_channels

import kotlin.math.abs
import kotlin.math.min

abstract class AudioTrackBuffer constructor(val loop: Boolean) {
    var position: Int = 0

    abstract fun getSamples(sampleCount: Int): IntArray
    abstract fun isComplete(): Boolean
    abstract fun dispose()
}

class RawAudioBuffer constructor(private val samples: IntArray, loop: Boolean, delay: Int): AudioTrackBuffer(loop) {

    init {
        position = -delay
    }

    override fun getSamples(sampleCount: Int): IntArray {
        val slice: IntArray

        if (position < 0) {
            slice = IntArray(sampleCount) { 0 }

            if (position + sampleCount < 0) {
                position += sampleCount
                return slice
            }

            val offset = abs(position)
            samples.copyInto(slice, offset, 0, min(sampleCount - offset, samples.size)) // Error
        } else {
            slice = samples.copyOfRange(position, min(position + sampleCount, samples.size))
            position += slice.size
        }

        return slice
    }

    override fun isComplete(): Boolean {
        return position >= samples.size
    }

    override fun dispose() {}
}
```

And here is the compile error:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on SM N960U in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...
Resolving dependencies...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
e: E:\flutter\workspace\audio_channels\android\src\main\kotlin\com\----\audio_channels\AudioTrackBuffer.kt: (33, 21): Unresolved reference: copyInto

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':audio_channels:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: did you try making a backing field for samples?

Comment: which Kotlin version you have used? I just check and see that `copyInto` available from 1.3

Comment: @SaedNabil I'm not sure what you mean. I'm relatively new to Kotlin, but it was my understanding that putting `private val samples` in the primary constructor definition implicitly made `samples` into a private class field. Why would I need to have a backing field for it? It's not null, as I can perform other actions on it (like printing it), I just can't do `copyInto` for some reason.

Comment: @PhanVanLinh In the project gradle.build, it said `ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.71'`. I changed this to `ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.40'` and it worked. If you want to post an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: You are totally correct, but it was not clear to me that you can access the object but not the the specific copyinto ,it doesn't make any sense to me, so I thought may be that was the problem,No worries , hence it solved now,

Comment: @Abion47 How it was available from the Intellisense if it was not available ,any ideas?

Comment: @SaedNabil My guess is the Kotlin plugin was configured to use the latest version of Kotlin for the Intellisense while the compiler was set to use an older version.

Comment: yes, apparently that is the case .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `copyInto` function available since kotlin `1.3`. Currently, you are using `1.2.71` then you get error `Unresolved reference: copyInto`.
Therefore, update your app kotlin version to >= 1.3 will solve your problem